# Using tabcoltrol in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin

I would using control as Tab control same as wpf xaml in my project xamarin form but i can not found any possible solution, I would design tab as image below
[image]

please help me! thanks

Comment: You could use the plugin from nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.TabView/ .

Comment: how to add contentpage/contentview in tabitems of Tabview. I tried binding itemsource of tabviewcontrol becaause list tabitem but not working. Please help me thanks!

Comment: Here is a sample https://github.com/chaosifier/TabView/blob/master/TabViewSample/TabViewSample/MainPage.xaml which maybe can help you .